# ERC-20 interface decimal issue

Tags: solidity, erc-20, decimals

i have created erc20 token with 100000  supply and decimal with 0.

i wonder that if i ask an exchange to list my token. Are these decimal is problem?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can list your token.
For example you can check that token 0x957c30ab0426e0c93cd8241e2c60392d08c6ac8e
If you add liquidity to dexes everybody can exchange your token with your pair like yourToken/Eth pair.